# Second dual of the image of a Banach space under a continuous linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, adjoint-operators, dual-spaces

Let $E$ and $F$ be Banach spaces and $T:E\to F$ a continuous linear operator. Is this following equality correct?
$$(T E)''=T''E''$$

*Notes*:

- $E''$ is the bidual of $E$
- $T''$ is the second adjoint of $T$
- $TE=\{Tu:u\in E\}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. To state this more precisely, introduce the canonical inclusions $\rho_E:E\to E''$ and $\rho_F:F\to F''$. The claim follows from the commutative diagram  (which I won't draw),
$$
T''\circ \rho_E = \rho_F\circ T
\tag1$$
(Equal operators have the same range.)

For any $x\in E$ and any $f^*\in F'$, the definition of adjoint operator yields 
$$
\langle T''\rho_E(x), f^*\rangle = 
\langle \rho_E(x), T'f^*\rangle = 
\langle x, T'f^*\rangle = 
\langle Tx, f^*\rangle = 
\langle \rho_F(Tx), f^*\rangle  
$$
where angle brackets mean the natural pairing of a space with its dual. Since $f^*$ was arbitrary, we get
$$
 T''\rho_E(x) = \rho_F(Tx)
$$
which is (1).